# Created a folder in themes for Concrete. How do I register that theme?

Tags: php, html, themes, concrete5

How do I register the folder with the layouts I created. When I go to edit and then design I dont see my theme there. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**General**
A theme should at least have a default.php and view.php file in the folder.
Do not forget to clear your cache, as the cache *might* prevent you from viewing your newly created theme.

**Concrete5.6 and less**
Add a description.txt file with on line 1 the title of your theme and on the second line the desciption of your theme.

**Concrete5.7 and 8**
You should have a page_theme.php file in your theme folder.
In the page_theme.php you should have 2 functions :

```
public function getThemeName()
{
    return t('My custom theme');
}

public function getThemeDescription()
{
    return t('Amazing theme build by xxxxxxxx.');
}
```

As an example: you can have a look at the page_theme.php located at /concrete/themes/elemental

Do not forget to change the namespace to your theme ([see more info about namespace camelcasing here](https://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/5-7-discussion/page_theme.php-not-working-in-my-custom-theme))